# Charge Conjugation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, dirac-matrices, charge-conjugation

For my calculations I need to know how charge conjugation acts on the Spin 3/2 propagator. The charge conjugation operator $C$ is calculated as $C= i\gamma^2\gamma^0$. The Spin 3/2 propagator is

$$
S_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{\gamma^\mu p_\mu + M}{p^2 - M^2}\left(-g_{\alpha\beta} + \frac{1}{3} \gamma_\alpha\gamma_\beta + \frac{1}{3M}(\gamma_\alpha p_\beta-\gamma_\beta p_\alpha) + \frac{2}{3M^2}p_\alpha p_\beta\right).
$$
My ansatz for a solution:
I know that the following terms transform as

$$
C\gamma_\mu C^{-1}=-(\gamma_\mu)^T\\
C\gamma_5C^{-1}=\gamma_5 \text{(in the Dirac basis)}\\
C\gamma_\mu \gamma_5 C^{-1}=(\gamma_\mu \gamma_5)^T\\
C \sigma_{\mu\nu}C^{-1}=-(\sigma_{\mu\nu})^T \text{(the commutator of Dirac matrices)}
$$

With this and the fact that
$$
\gamma_\mu \gamma_\alpha \gamma_\beta=g_{\mu\alpha}\gamma_\beta + g_{\alpha\beta}\gamma_\mu -g_{\mu\beta}\gamma_\alpha -i \epsilon_{\rho \mu \alpha \beta}\gamma^\rho \gamma_5
$$
we can easily calculate the transformation containing zero, one and three Dirac matrices. But I do not know how to calculate the transformation on two Dirac matrices. I also know that the first factor in the propagator which is equal to the spin 1/2 propagator, commutates with the rest. But I don't know how to use it to calculate the total transformation.
$$

Comment: Don't you just do $C \gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu C^{-1} = C \gamma_\mu C^{-1} C \gamma_\nu C^{-1}$?

Comment: You are correct! Thank you, I really should have thought of that myself!